# Count even numbers in matrix

Tags: c, assembly, x86

In this function I want to get even numbers in matrix. My parameters are a bidimensional pointer and the dimensions of matrix.
Anyone could help me? Where I got wrong...

```
    subl    $12, %esp                    # 12 bytes to local variables

    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)                # counter = 0
    movl    8(%ebp), %esi               # **m
    movl    $0, %ebx                     # i = 0
it_rows:
    cmpl    12(%ebp), %ebx              # while(i != y)
    jz      end                         # if not equal jump
    leal    (%esi, %ebx, 4), %edi       # m+i
    movl    $0, %ecx                     # j = 0
it_col:
    cmpl    16(%ebp), %ecx              # while(j != k)
    jz      next_row
    movl    (%edi, %ecx, 4), %eax       # *(*(m+i)+j)
    andl    $0x1, %eax               # LSB
    cmpl    $0, %eax                     # LSB == 0
    jnz     not_even
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax             # counter
    incl    %eax                        # counter++
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)             # update local variable
not_even:
    incl    %ecx                        # j++
    jmp     it_col
next_row:
    incl    %ebx                        # i++
    jmp     it_rows
```

My implementation in C:

```
int count_even_matrix(int **m, int y, int k) {
    int i, j;
    int c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            if(*(*(m+i)+j)%2 == 0) {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: How is the matrix declared?

Comment: You have not shown the complete assembly-language function, and you're not honoring the calling convention (you don't save or restore callee-save registers or set up %ebp properly) - so I can't experiment with your code myself, so I'm not motivated to help you with it.

Comment: I do have a piece of advice, though: compare your assembly code _line by line_ with the result of running your C code through `gcc -m32 -march=native -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-schedule-insns -fno-schedule-insns2 -O2 -S`.  Where they differ, assume the compiler knows something you don't, and research that something.  (You can safely ignore all of the lines reading `.cfi_something blah blah blah`.)

Comment: What is the question? What part of the code is not working? Does the C implementation work?

Comment: This is part of code, initially I reserve 12 bytes to local variables.
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $12, %esp

Matrix is declared as a bidimensional pointer as C implementation. I want to write my C implementation to assembly.

Comment: @BrunoAlves Edit the question to show the code of the entire function, or no one will help you any further.

Comment: @BrunoAlves Also, why do you feel you need to "write your C implementation to assembly" in the first place?

Comment: No idea what is not working for you (plus comments above sum it up, why I don't want to try to guess), but the whole test for even + increment can be done without branching: `and eax,1` `dec eax` `sub [ebp-12],eax` (intel syntax, does `even = even - ((LSB&1) - 1);` )

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` with

```
if ((m[i][j] % 2 ) == 0) {    
     c++;  
 }
```

`i` is your matrix rows index, and `j` the columns index. The two `for` already increment them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a beginner in C, but if you're passing the array name of your two dimensional array to your function, you're actually passing a pointer to the first element of the array, which in this case is a 3 element one dimensional array.  So I believe that your pointer should be declared as int (*m)[3].

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write my C implementation to assembly.

Your assembly has just one error: the `leal`, which has to be `movl`. Consider, what you call *a bidimensional pointer* is, as the type `int **` conveys, a pointer to pointers to `int`s. With

```
    leal    (%esi, %ebx, 4), %edi       # m+i
```

you only *load the address* of the pointer to the `int`s in the *ebx*th row, but you actually need the value of that pointer, i. e. the address of the `int`s, and that you get with

```
    movl    (%esi, %ebx, 4), %edi       # *(m+i)
```